# Find Integers and float numbers in txt file

Tags: java, file, txt

I have a problem with a simple code nd don't know how to do it;
I have 3 txt files.
First txt file looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 4.5 4,6 6.8 8,9
1 3 4 5 8 9,2 6,3 6,7 8.9
```

I would like to read numbers from this txt file and save integers to one txt file and floats to another.

Comment: Please describe what the issue is with your code. And what is the comma in the sample, a separator or a decimal comma, is 6,7 the same as 6.7 or 6 and 7?

Comment: Does the file can only have numbers or letters as well? Are all the integers digits or could it be >9? (looks like a good practice question)

Comment: 6,7 is the same as 6.7, file can only have numbers, integers could be >9; I'm sorry for being so imprecise

Comment: this code just doesn't work and I don't know why

Comment: @MarekOS - I have tested [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64834562/10819573) to be working. You can comment below this code confirming the same if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following easy steps:

1. When you read a line, split it on whitespace and get an array of tokens.
2. While processing each token,

   - Trim any leading and trailing whitespace and then replace `,` with `.`
   - First check if the token can be parsed into an `int`. If yes, write it into `outInt` (the writer for integers). Otherwise, check if the token can be parsed into `float`. If yes, write it into `outFloat` (the writer for floats). Otherwise, ignore it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("t.txt"));
        BufferedWriter outInt = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("t2.txt"));
        BufferedWriter outFloat = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("t3.txt"));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {// Read until EOF is reached
            // Split the line on whitespace and get an array of tokens
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

            // Process each token
            for (String s : tokens) {
                // Trim any leading and trailing whitespace and then replace , with .
                s = s.trim().replace(',', '.');

                // First check if the token can be parsed into an int
                try {
                    Integer.parseInt(s);
                    // If yes, write it into outInt
                    outInt.write(s + " ");
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Otherwise, check if token can be parsed into float
                    try {
                        Float.parseFloat(s);
                        // If yes, write it into outFloat
                        outFloat.write(s + " ");
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        // Otherwise, ignore it
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        in.close();
        outInt.close();
        outFloat.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius, THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `,` is also a decimal separator `.` it may be possible to unify this characters (replace `,` with `.`).

```java
static void readAndWriteNumbers(String inputFile, String intNums, String dblNums) throws IOException {
    // Use StringBuilder to collect the int and double numbers separately
    StringBuilder ints = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder dbls = new StringBuilder();
    
    Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))        // stream of string
         .map(str -> str.replace(',', '.'))  // unify decimal separators
         .map(str -> { 
             Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+")).forEach(v -> {  // split each line into tokens
                 if (v.contains(".")) {
                    if (dbls.length() > 0 && !dbls.toString().endsWith(System.lineSeparator())) {
                        dbls.append("  ");
                    }
                    dbls.append(v);
                 }
                 else {
                    if (ints.length() > 0 && !ints.toString().endsWith(System.lineSeparator())) {
                        ints.append("  ");
                    }
                    ints.append(v);
                 }
             }); 
             return System.lineSeparator();                  // return new-line
         })
         .forEach(s -> { ints.append(s); dbls.append(s); }); // keep lines in the results

    // write the files using the contents from the string builders
    try (
        FileWriter intWriter = new FileWriter(intNums);
        FileWriter dblWriter = new FileWriter(dblNums);
    ) {
        intWriter.write(ints.toString());
        dblWriter.write(dbls.toString());
    }
}

// test
readAndWriteNumbers("test.dat", "ints.dat", "dbls.dat");
```

Output

```
//ints.dat
1    2    3    4    5  
1    3    4    5    8  

// dbls.dat
4.5  4.6  6.8  8.9
9.2  6.3  6.7  8.9
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you tell me where to paste the paths to the files?

Comment: The paths are passed as strings to `readAndWriteNumbers(String inputFile, String intNums, String dblNums)`, the first parameter is the path to the input file, the other two are the paths to the outputs.